# Why Is My Array Not Working And How to Fix It

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, openframeworks

The code that I'm using works to create a 10 by 10 block of objects which are drawn later in the program. I want the program to skip the x and y values of object 8 and 9 in both lines.

If the code is slightly altered to say If (Skip[0] == i), it works perfectly, but only for the one value, which would need to be repeated and is what I'm trying to avoid by setting up an array. I don't know very much about coding so try to simplify as best you can.

Doesn't Work

```
int Skip[2] = { 8, 9 };

            for (int j = 0; j <= 10 - 1; j++) {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 10 - 1; i++) {

                    for (int m = 0; m <= 1; m++) {
                        if (i == Skip[m]) {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }

                    x[i][j] = 0 + i * 50;
                    y[i][j] = 0 + j * 50;
                }
            }
```

Does Work

```
int Skip[2] = { 8, 9 };

            for (int j = 0; j <= 10 - 1; j++) {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 10 - 1; i++) {

                        if (i == Skip[0]) {
                            continue;
                        }

                    x[i][j] = 0 + i * 50;
                    y[i][j] = 0 + j * 50;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Sidenote: `j <= 10 - 1` is the same as `j < 10`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers.  You need to debug your code and create a [mre].

Answer (score 2):

In the non-working example, `continue` applies to the loop over `m`. That whole loop is an elaborate no-op - it has absolutely no effect.

In the working example, `continue` applies to the loop over `i`, and has the effect of aborting that iteration early and skipping to the next one.

Comment: Just knowing that the loop was non-functioning helped me restructure the code and it's working now. I just didn't understand why something I thought should work wasn't. Thank you for clarifying why.

Answer (score 1):

To add to [@Igor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57941156/10957435), change `continue` to `break` to break the inner loop, but continue the outer loop. It should have the effect you intend:

```
for (int j = 0; j <= 10 - 1; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10 - 1; i++) {

        for (int m = 0; m <= 1; m++) {
            if (i == Skip[m]) {
                 // This breaks the m loop, but continues the i loop
                 break;
            }
        }

        x[i][j] = 0 + i * 50;
        y[i][j] = 0 + j * 50
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes no difference. Whether the innermost loop breaks early, or runs through to completion, the outcome of the following code is exactly the same. The loop over `m` is a no-op here, too.